# Table Name is null in the sqlite database in android device

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I am building a simple app which stores some contacts and retrieves contacts in android phone device.

I have created my own database and a table and inserting the values to the table in phone.

My phone is not rooted. So I cannot access the files, but I see that values are stored in the table. And tested on a emulator also. Till here it is fine.

Display all the contacts in a list by fetching data from table. This is also fine.

But the problem is When I am trying to delete the record, it shows the table name is null in the logcat(not an exception), and the data is not deleted. But in emulator the data is getting deleted from table. I am not able to achieve this through phone.

This is my code for deleting,

```
 public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
            .getMenuInfo();
    int menuItemIndex = item.getItemId();
    String[] menuItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu);
    String menuItemName = menuItems[menuItemIndex];
    String listItemName = Customers[info.position];

    if (item.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Delete")) {
        Toast.makeText(
                context,
                "Selected List item is: " + listItemName + "MenuItem is: "
                        + menuItemName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        DB = context.openOrCreateDatabase("CustomerDetails.db",
                MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        try {
            int pos = info.position;
            pos = pos + 1;
            Log.d("", "customers[pos]: " + Customers[info.position]);
            Cursor c = DB
                    .rawQuery(
                            "Select customer_id,first_name,last_name from CustomerInfo",
                            null);
            int rowCount = c.getCount();

            DB.delete(Table_name,
                    "customer_id" + "=" + String.valueOf(pos), null);

            DB.close();
            Log.d("", "" + String.valueOf(pos));
            Toast.makeText(context, "Deleted Customer", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            // Customers[info.position]=null;
            getCustomers();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Delete unsuccessfull",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
```

this is my logcat,

```
07-02 10:12:42.976: D/Cursor(1560): Database path: CustomerDetails.db
07-02 10:12:42.976: D/Cursor(1560): Table name   : null
07-02 10:12:42.984: D/Cursor(1560): Database path: CustomerDetails.db
07-02 10:12:42.984: D/Cursor(1560): Table name   : null
```

Don't know the reason why data is not being deleted. Data exists in the table.

Please correct my code. 
  Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: what is the value of `Table_name ` and you dont need to specify .db extention in database name.

Comment: @Lucifier, I specified the value of Table_name like this:  String Table_name = "CustomerInfo";  Its a global declaration.

Comment: Ya, I thought so, and what is the data type of your customer_id field ?

Comment: customer_id is of type integer autoincrement

Comment: @Lucifier, please see the code I have edited. I mentioned the specification for creating table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your customer_id is of type integer while in you are passing it as String type in following line,

```
DB.delete(Table_name,"customer_id" + "=" + String.valueOf(pos), null);
```

that's why it is returning `false`, try using it as integer itself as follows,

```
DB.delete(Table_name,"customer_id" + "=" + pos, null);
```

Comment: Thanks. Great help. I didn't observe this. I would have corrected for myself if atleast an exception is thrown.

Comment: Emulator & real device both are different environment, Emulator never 100% gurantees to give real output

Answer (score 0):

If possible try this method also.

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class RegistrationAdapter {
    SQLiteDatabase database_ob;
    RegistrationOpenHelper openHelper_ob;
    Context context;

    public RegistrationAdapter(Context c) {
        context = c;
    }

    public RegistrationAdapter opnToRead() {
        openHelper_ob = new RegistrationOpenHelper(context,
                openHelper_ob.DATABASE_NAME, null, openHelper_ob.VERSION);
        database_ob = openHelper_ob.getReadableDatabase();
        return this;

    }

    public RegistrationAdapter opnToWrite() {
        openHelper_ob = new RegistrationOpenHelper(context,
                openHelper_ob.DATABASE_NAME, null, openHelper_ob.VERSION);
        database_ob = openHelper_ob.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;

    }

    public void Close() {
        database_ob.close();
    }

    public long insertDetails(String fname, String lname) {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(openHelper_ob.FNAME, fname);
        contentValues.put(openHelper_ob.LNAME, lname);
        opnToWrite();
        long val = database_ob.insert(openHelper_ob.TABLE_NAME, null,
                contentValues);
        Close();
        return val;

    }

    public Cursor queryName() {
        String[] cols = { openHelper_ob.KEY_ID, openHelper_ob.FNAME,
                openHelper_ob.LNAME };
        opnToWrite();
        Cursor c = database_ob.query(openHelper_ob.TABLE_NAME, cols, null,
                null, null, null, null);

        return c;

    }

    public Cursor queryAll(int nameId) {
        String[] cols = { openHelper_ob.KEY_ID, openHelper_ob.FNAME,
                openHelper_ob.LNAME };
        opnToWrite();
        Cursor c = database_ob.query(openHelper_ob.TABLE_NAME, cols,
                openHelper_ob.KEY_ID + "=" + nameId, null, null, null, null);

        return c;

    }

    public long updateldetail(int rowId, String fname, String lname) {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(openHelper_ob.FNAME, fname);
        contentValues.put(openHelper_ob.LNAME, lname);
        opnToWrite();
        long val = database_ob.update(openHelper_ob.TABLE_NAME, contentValues,
                openHelper_ob.KEY_ID + "=" + rowId, null);
        Close();
        return val;
    }

    public int deletOneRecord(int rowId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        opnToWrite();
        int val = database_ob.delete(openHelper_ob.TABLE_NAME,
                openHelper_ob.KEY_ID + "=" + rowId, null);
        Close();
        return val;
    }

}
```

openhelper.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class RegistrationOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "REGISTRATION_DB";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "REGISTRATION_TABLE";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME_ONE = "REGISTRATION_TABLE_ONE";
    public static final int VERSION = 1;
    public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
    public static final String FNAME = "F_NAME";
    public static final String PKEY_ID = "pid";
    public static final String PROFILE = "profile";
    public static final String LNAME = "L_NAME";
    public static final String SCRIPT = "create table " + TABLE_NAME + " ("
            + KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + FNAME
            + " text not null, " + LNAME + " text not null );";

    public static final String PROFILE_TABLE = "create table " + TABLE_NAME_ONE + " ("
            + PKEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + PROFILE
            + " text not null, );";

  /* public static final String PROFILE_TABLE="create table profiletable(profileid integer primary key autoincrement,profilename text null);";
   public static final String VALUE_TABLE="create table valuetable(id integer primary key autoincrement,value text null,delay );";
   */


    public RegistrationOpenHelper(Context context, String name,
            CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL(SCRIPT);
        db.execSQL(PROFILE_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("drop table " + TABLE_NAME);
        db.execSQL("drop table "+TABLE_NAME_ONE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

}
```